# Do all polynomials of degree 2 form a subspace of $F(-\infty,\infty)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $F(-\infty,\infty)$ be a vector space, V. Do polynomials of degree 2 form a subspace of this vector space?

Comment: Not sure what $F$ is. But ... is the $0$ polynomial a polynomial of degree $2$?

Comment: $x^2$ is a polynomial of degree 2, and so is $5x - x^2$, but their sum isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero element here is certainly not any polynomial of degree $2$, so it is not a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

If you instead asked: "do all polynomials with degree two or less form a vector space", then the answer would be yes.

They wouldn't form a (multiplicative) algebra though.